# How do I make a score label increase in cocos2d

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, label, increment

so I have a  label and I would like that when an image collide with another image it increase of 10 . score = score +10; but instead of this it increase of 40 I don't know why . so here is my code :

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init] )) {

        [self schedule:@selector(update:)];

        score = 0;

        scoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score] fontName:@"PUSAB___.TTF" fontSize:15 ];
        scoreLabel.position=ccp(450,30);
        [self addChild:scoreLabel];
    }
}

- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(mangeurRect, targetRect)) {
        [targetsToDelete addObject:target];     
        score=score + 10; ;// Not really, but your score changes somehow...
        [scoreLabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score]];
    }                       
}
```

sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: Your English is fine. The code formatting, however... :)

Comment: lol !! so what is the problem please ?? :)

Comment: how do you initialize / obtain "mangeurRect" and "targetRect"? Are these screen-relative rects that need update every frame or constant local sprite bounding boxes?

Comment: these are initialize in the update method is it good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is no frame you are getting in the CGRectIntersectsRect. You should Try the Below code

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {

if (CGRectIntersectsRect([mangeurRect frame], [targetRect frame])) {
    [targetsToDelete addObject:target];     
    score += 10;
    [scoreLabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score]];
}
```

}

**OR**

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {

if (CGRectIntersectsRect([mangeurRect boundingBox], [targetRect boundingBox])) {
    [targetsToDelete addObject:target];     
    score += 10; 
    [scoreLabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score]];
}
```

}

By this you would probably get the score increased whenever the images collide with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check whether your target is not already in targets to delete as follows, in case the process that actually empties the targetsToDelete structure is somehow delayed for a few ticks:

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
    if ([targetsToDelete containsObject:target]) return;    // already scored.
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(mangeurRect, targetRect)) {
        [targetsToDelete addObject:target];     
        score=score + 10; ;// Not really, but your score changes somehow...
        [scoreLabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score]];
    }                       
}
```

the above assumes that targetsToDelete is an NSMutableArray.

Comment: try to add some logs to the code and see when the score is changed, based on the objects that you are checking.

Answer (score 0):

Your update method is not complete. Try this:

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(mangeurRect, targetRect)) {
        [targetsToDelete addObject:target];     
        score=score + 10; ;// Not really, but your score changes somehow...
        [scoreLabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score]];

        //do something with your targetsToDelete array.. 
        for (CCSprite *target in targetsToDelete) {
         //[_targets removeObject:target]; //uncomment this line, if you have saved your targets in a _targets array
         [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];                                 
        }
    }                       
}
```

Ref: http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial